# Circles and canvas and math, oh my

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle on a canvas with my mouse, but my math is wrong and I can't figure out how to fix it. I want the top (or bottom) of the circle and the side of the circle to be aligned with the crosshairs of the cursor as you click-drag to make the circle.

I've got a [fiddle set up here](http://jsfiddle.net/n17hqe14/2/).

The math in question looks like this:

```
    var centerx = self.startDragPos.x + (mouse.x-self.startDragPos.x)/2;
    var centery = self.startDragPos.y + (mouse.y-self.startDragPos.y)/2;
    var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.startDragPos.x - mouse.x, 2) + Math.pow(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.x, 2))/2;

    ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

The formulas look right, where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for all the great suggestions. I didn't ask the question very clearly, but Av Avt gave me the clue I needed to figure it out. In case you were wondering what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/n17hqe14/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula looks right imo, but with a typo: `Math.pow(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.x, 2)` should be `Math.pow(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.y, 2)` isn't it?

```
var centerx = self.startDragPos.x + (mouse.x-self.startDragPos.x)/2;
var centery = self.startDragPos.y + (mouse.y-self.startDragPos.y)/2;
var radius = Math.min(Math.abs(self.startDragPos.x - mouse.x), Math.abs(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.y))/2;

ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Comment: This is cool, this keeps the crosshairs on the circumference. Not quite what I'm looking for but +1.

Comment: Eh, could you update with a image of what exactly you want? Because no matter how I read it your description is talking about this result...

Comment: In other words.. If we were drawing a square instead of a circle, the entire circle should fit inside the suare.

Comment: now that I'm seeing this I'm realizing that I have to figure out a way to make the circle oblong. but you gave me what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: An oblong circle is called an ellipse. There are commands for that shape. `void ctx.ellipse(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, rotation, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);`.

Comment: true. support for ellise is limited evidently. it's "not a function" in latest firefox on mac, evidentally.

Answer (score 3):

```
var centerx = startDragPos.x;
var centery = startDragPos.y;
var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerx - mouse.x, 2) + Math.pow(centery - mouse.y, 2));
```

Comment: This keeps the crosshairs on the circumference. I want the the crosshairs aligned with the top and side of the circle

Comment: The crosshairs cannot be aligned with the 'top and side' at the same time unless it makes a 45 degrees angle with the center.

Answer (score 1):

@EmeraldWeapon provided you a roundabout way to align circle line to the crosshairs. A simpler modification to do this is to correct the typo in your `radius` variable.

```
var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.startDragPos.x - mouse.x, 2) + Math.pow(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.x, 2))/2;
```

Should be

```
var radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(self.startDragPos.x - mouse.x, 2) + Math.pow(self.startDragPos.y - mouse.y, 2))/2;
```

However, @EmeraldWeapon's solution is more efficient than simply correcting the typo.

Here's the tricky part, this won't align the top/bottom and left/right of the circle to the crosshairs, it'll make it so the crosshairs marks the exact placing of the line of the circle.

To get the top/bottom and left/right alignment is trickier, and that escapes me, at the moment. At the very least, this will make the drawing of a circle more predictable.

Answer (score 1):

As another variation in the quest to successively approximate your vaguely stated goal try this:

```
var centerx = (mouse.x+startDragPos.x)/2;
var centery = (mouse.y+startDragPos.y)/2;
var radius = Math.min(Math.abs(startDragPos.x - mouse.x), Math.abs(startDragPos.y - mouse.y))/2;
```

It takes the rectangle defined by the opposite vertices `startDragpos.(x,y)` and `mouse.(x,y)` and draws the largest centered circle still inside the rectangle.

Comment: From his comment in my answer it seems this is what he's actually looking for :)

Comment: @AvAvt what i'm actually looking for is a combination of your answer and this: http://jsfiddle.net/n17hqe14/5/

Comment: You just need to divide rx and ry by 2 to get the desired effect.